# Add data based on query to API response (Django REST Framework)

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am building an API for a loan payment calculator app with Python, Django, and Django REST frameworks.

For the calculation to work, the data about loan terms and loan amounts that a user gives in their request needs to be accessed and used together with the data from the database. I am stuck on how to accomplish this. I'd like to have a key 'payment' in JSON response, with a value that equals the amount calculated.

Even though I am now passing context data from view to serializer, the request data does not seem to be passed correctly, because both request

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/offer/
```

and request

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/offer/?price=10000000&deposit=10&term=20
```

produce the same JSON-response, where "payment" equals 'null':

```
[
    {
        "bank_name": "bank_one",
        "payment": null,
        "term_min": 10,
        "term_max": 30,
        "rate_min": 1.6,
        "rate_max": 9.8,
        "payment_min": 1000000,
        "payment_max": 10000000
    }
]
```

These are my model, serializer, and view:

**models.py:**

```
class Offer(models.Model):
    
    term_min = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    term_max = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    rate_min = models.FloatField()
    rate_max = models.FloatField()
    payment_min = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    payment_max = models.PositiveIntegerField()
```

**serializers.py:**

```
class OfferSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    payment = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def validate(self, data):
        price = self.context['price']
        deposit = self.context['deposit']
        term = self.context['term']
        return data

    def create(self, validated_data):
        price = self.context['price']
        deposit = self.context['deposit']
        term = self.context['term']
                
        validated_data['price'] = price
        validated_data['deposit'] = deposit
        validated_data['term'] = term
        offer = Offer.objects.create(**validated_data)
        return offer

    class Meta:
        model = Offer
        fields = ['bank_name', 'payment', 'term_min', 'term_max', 'rate_min', 'rate_max', 'payment_min', 'payment_max']

    def get_payment(self, obj):

        if self.context['term'] and self.context['price'] and self.context['deposit']:

            if self.context['term'] == obj.term_min:
                int_rate = obj.rate_min
            elif self.context['term'] == obj.term_max:
                int_rate = obj.rate_max
            else:
                term_proportion = (self.context['term'] - obj.term_min)/(obj.term_max - obj.term_min)
                int_rate = (obj.rate_max / 100 - obj.rate_min/100) * term_proportion
            
            loan = int(self.context['price']) - int(self.context['price']) * (int(self.context['deposit']) / 100)
            term_in_months = 12 * self.context['term']
            monthly_pmt = loan * ((1 + int_rate) ** term_in_months) / ((1 + int_rate) ** term_in_months - 1)
            return monthly_pmt
```

**views.py:**

```
class OfferViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Offer.objects.all()
    serializer_class = OfferSerializer

    def get_serializer_context(self):
        context = super(OfferViewSet, self).get_serializer_context()
        context.update({"deposit": self.request.POST.get("deposit", None)})
        context.update({"price": self.request.POST.get("price", None)})
        context.update({"term": self.request.POST.get("term", None)})
        return context

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)

    
    def get_queryset(self, *args,**kwargs):
        queryset = super().get_queryset(*args, **kwargs)
        price = self.request.GET.get('price', None)
        deposit = self.request.GET.get('deposit', None)
        term = self.request.GET.get('term', None)
        if price and deposit and term:
            loan_amount = int(price) - int(price) * (int(deposit) / 100)
            queryset = queryset.filter(term_min__lte=term, term_max__gte=term, payment_min__lte=loan_amount, payment_max__gte=loan_amount)
            return queryset
        else:
            return Offer.objects.all()
```

Comment: Did you have a look at [serializers.SerializerMethodField](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield) ?

Comment: @Art yes I did. However it seems to work only for fields that can be accessed in the data base. My issue is that I cannot see the way to add data that user passes as query parameters (serializer does not have 'request' as a possible parameter, it can have only self and object - which is all database data)

Comment: You can always pass in a request to the serializer as context.

Comment: Maybe I just misunderstand the documentation. For SerializerMethodField it says: "The serializer method referred to by the method_name argument should accept a single argument (in addition to self), which is the object being serialized. " So the method does not allow for a third parameter. Where does one pass context?

Comment: You pass context from view, `SampleSerializer(data={}, context={'request': request})`

Comment: @Art Thanks! I have now changed the code so as to pass context to my serializer, but it looks like I did something wrong because now both requests with query parameters and without them return the same API response...

Comment: Try using the print statement inside `get_payment`  method of your serializer class to check if the `if` condition is working.

Comment: @Art Thank you very much, I've identified what the problem was!

Answer (score 0):

To add data from query parameters, took me:

1. add context from view to serializer (the following search result was very helpful: https://ilovedjango.com/django/rest-api-framework/views/tips/context-in-django-rest-framework/). This required overriding `get_serializer_context` and `create` methods in my ModelViewSet. The change I made to `views.py` file in my post was as follows:

```
def get_serializer_context(self):
        context = super(OfferViewSet, self).get_serializer_context()
        context.update({"deposit": self.request.GET.get("deposit", None)})
        context.update({"price": self.request.GET.get("price", None)})
        context.update({"term": self.request.GET.get("term", None)})
        return context
```

2. use `SerializerMethodField` (see DRF documentation: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield) to add calculated field to serializer.